# Blender viewport facing orientation is -Y

Tags: 3d-view, camera, axis, startup-file

when I start a new file in Blender its viewport has -Y axis pointing forwards, X goes right by default, Z is up by default.
How can I rotate the viewport orientation to have +Y forwards and X still to right?
Having pressed ctrl-1 rotates viewport axis to: Y going forwards but X goes left.
[image: Start-up]

[image: After ctrl-1]

p.s.: I just realized its something deeper then hotkeys issue: no matter how you update the viewport the location of X and Y would always be wrong. Id love an advice how to change that to X right, Y forward, Z up...

Comment: that's the definition of xyz - you cannot change that AFAIK

Comment: But any video on Blender I watched to test it has X to right and +Y to forward

Comment: can u link a tutorial example pls?

Comment: lets say this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw

Comment: you are right...try to investigate...

Answer (score 3):

Gizmo showing -Y means you're in *Front View*
You can switch to Y (back view) by clicking on the gizmo axis.

[image]

Comment: Well, I got it, Blender Z is not just up  it is up relatively to X and Y, so if you rotate classc XYZ (Z is forward) to make it Blender's Z you get -Y pointing forward. Clear, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, going through the videos I was watching I noticed the thing while the viewport axis gizmo gets tilted the +Y axis goes behind X, while in front gizmo view it seems to show in front. With a difference that in my case it just adds minus to Y (still dont know why), but the relationships between X and Y are still the same - +Y is located positively behind X axis, -Y goes front. This might look like an answer, despite I dont really get this (as well as Z up :)